# Including a php file from another server in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello i am try to include a PHP class (Payroll.php) found on another server since it requires the main module that has been written in pure PHP in my Laravel sub-module. I was given the url to the php file on the other server and have been tasked with using it to fetch the employees from the main module to be used in my module. Almost all the solutions i found on the internet where for cases where the laravel code and the php code exist on the same server. I tried several approaches such as including the file directly (which is giving me class not found) and using things like guzzle and so on (which failed since it is not an API). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it in same server?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu no the php class is hosted while the laravel is still local. Also when the laravel script is finally hosted it will be on a different server

Comment: Can you try to use curl request?

Comment: I tried using cURL but it was returning nothing because it is not an API call but rather a php class with somefunctions in it

Comment: Are they dependent on other classes and methods belongs to other classes or standalone class?

Comment: No they are dependent on other classes which is the main reason why i cant simply copy them over to my module